# factor $x^3+2x^2+2x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

factor $x^3+2x^2+2x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$

Is there a good strategy other than finding (guessing until you find a root) a root than using the division algorithm? Its not a very hard question to do but I am asking incase I come across a difficult one in which finding a root may not be so easy.

Comment: Here, we know that since $-1 + 2 - 2 + 1 = 0$, that $x \equiv -1$ is a solution. I don't know if you used that test or not, but it would help here.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no better way to factor a cubic over a small finite field than to substitute till you get a root.  No root implies a cubic is irreducible.  That won't work though for higher degree polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

For larger fields or higher degree polynomials, there are better methods for factoring polynomials over finite fields, such as the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm (e.g. see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm)